# Webpack 4 - Add css file to multiple html files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to bundle a couple of html files and add one css files into all of them. But my webpack configuration add only css and js bundled files to index.html

My files looks like this: [image]

I want to add this main-hash.js and main-hash.css to all HTML files: about.html, index.html, contact.html

**Also** when I exclude index.html (comment below) from file-loader my index.html don't recognize paths for public folder `/images`. Any ideas ??

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/main.js',

  output: {
    filename: '[name]-[hash:8].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[hash:8].css'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        options: {
          plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],

          presets: [
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                modules: false
              }
            ]
          ]
        },
        exclude: '/node_modules/'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpeg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              publicPath: './src/images',
              outputPath: './assets',
              name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].html'
            }
          },
          { loader: 'extract-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              attrs: ['img:src']
            }
          }
        ],
        // HERE 
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.html')
      },

      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
          },
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          priority: -10,
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
        }
      },

      chunks: 'async',
      minChunks: 1,
      minSize: 30000,
      name: true
    }
  },

  devServer: {
    open: true
  }
};
```

Comment: Just link to the css files in the html or they can be imported in your main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple instances of the **HtmlWebpackPlugin**, one for each of your html files:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html'
  }),

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'about.html',
    template: './src/about.html'
  }),

  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'contact.html',
    template: './src/contact.html'
  }),

  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].css'
  }),

  new CleanWebpackPlugin()
],
```

This should inject the JS and CSS files into each html file.